# Why do memory barriers depend upon a variable?

Tags: c++

After doing some research regarding the overall purpose of memory barriers/fences, (at least I think that) I have a basic understanding of what they are for. During my research, I focused on the abstraction C++ makes as barriers seem to be hardware-specific and C++ is a low-level, yet universally usable language. However, there's one detail in the semantics of the standard library's abstraction of memory barriers that makes me question my understanding of them.

Regarding the C++ memory barrier `memory_order_acq_rel`, the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Constants) states (similar behaviour applies to the other barriers as well):

> All writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible before the modification and the modification is visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable.

On the processor level (as this restriction wouldn't exist without corresponding hardware restrictions): Why does the specification of a particular variable matter, if all previous changes are affected? For instance, the cache has to be flushed either way, hasn't it? What are the key advantages of this approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The standard specifies what needs to happen. It doesn't care how that is *actually* implemented at neither the software nor hardware layer. It just says "this must happen" how you do it is irrelevant.

Comment: "the cache has to be flushed" - no that's rarely a thing, major overkill for a memory barrier.

Comment: @harold What else could a processor do to fulfill these strong guarantees? This possibly varies from processor to processor, but what are the most common approaches? Maybe that's one of the reasons why the question even came up.

Comment: The CPU can flush an individual cache line, and not flush others.  So potentially an earlier write to variable on a different cache line would be flushed to memory (and visible to other CPUs) after then one used as a barrier.  Or, instead of flushing, the modified value can be passed along to other CPUs that also have that cache line.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I see, thank you. What's about the other modifications that happened prior to the atomic operation the "membar has been associated to"? Some part of the processor would need to keep track of those changes as well, right?

Comment: The processor does keep track of all the changes, because the data is still in its caches.  It just hasn't (necessarily) been written out to memory (or other CPUs) yet.  This depends a lot on the basic architecture.

Comment: @Quaffel [here is a patent](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/8959314.html), tricky to read though. By the way these guarantees are not that strong, on x86 an `memory_order_acq_rel`-fence is a no-op. A `memory_order_seq_cst`-fence corresponds to `mfence`. `lfence` and `sfence` also exist but are only useful in special circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Using atomic variables as a means to control memory barriers are just one way C++ gives you this control.  (Probably the most commonly used way, I might add.)

You don't need to use them though.

You can call functions such as [std::atomic_thread_fence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) and [std::atomic_signal_fence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_signal_fence) which implement the memory barrier semantics without any associated variable.

Comment: Or, in most cases, just use a `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` to protect access to shared stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should adhere to C++20 memory model. Invidia developers found a bug in the former model (composed a fully legal C++ code that follows standart rules but results in UB - data racing - due issues in the memory model) and I heard there were some other issues as well. Furthermore, C++ strives to be a general language that can function for wide spectrum of devices, thus some rules might be meaningless for certain devices and extremely important for other ones.

I am unsure about implementation details and what processor actually needs to do. However, besides processor actions on the atomic variable, it also informs the compiler about allowed and forbidden optimizations. E.g., local variables that are logically non-accessible from other threads never need to be reloaded into cache regardless of actions performed on atomic variables.